# C# Adding RDP Client Control to Tab Control

Tags: c#, tabs, controls, addition, rdp

I am making a program to manage multiple remote desktop sessions via Windows RDP. I found a tutorial that showed how to use the AxMsRdpClient2a control by dragging it in in to a control in form designer. But I want to create them on the fly inside a tab control (ie user clicks a button and makes new tab containing the remote desktop client). For some reason the AxMsRdpClient2a control is not showing up in the tab page when I run it. Here is the code I'm working with, any advice would be much appreciated!

```
            // Create a new tab for the remote desktop
        tabs[currentTab] = new TabPage();
        clients[currentTab] = new AxMsRdpClient2a();
        clients[currentTab].CreateControl();
        clients[currentTab].BringToFront();
        clients[currentTab].Parent = tabs[currentTab];
        clients[currentTab].ColorDepth = 16;
        //clients[currentTab].Location = new Point(0, 0);
        //clients[currentTab].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);

        tabs[currentTab].Controls.Add(clients[currentTab]);
        tabs[currentTab].Name = RemoteIP;
        tabs[currentTab].Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        tabs[currentTab].Size = remoteDesktopTabControl.Size;
        clients[currentTab].DesktopWidth = tabs[currentTab].Width;
        clients[currentTab].DesktopHeight = tabs[currentTab].Height;
        clients[currentTab].AdvancedSettings3.DisplayConnectionBar = true;
        tabs[currentTab].Text = RemoteIP;
        tabs[currentTab].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        remoteDesktopTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabs[currentTab]);
        tabs[currentTab].Controls.Add(new RichTextBox());

        remoteDesktopTabControl.SelectedTab = remoteDesktopTabControl.TabPages[remoteDesktopTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1];

        clients[currentTab].Server = RemoteIP;
        clients[currentTab].UserName = Username;
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)clients[currentTab].GetOcx();
        secured.ClearTextPassword = Password;
        clients[currentTab].ColorDepth = 16;
        clients[currentTab].Connect();

        currentTab++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I am dynamically creating the control

```
AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting newrdp = new AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting();
                newrdp.Name = "RDPControl";
                tab.Controls.Add(newrdp);
                tab.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(814, 508);

                tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab);
                tabControl.SelectedTab = tab;
                ConnectNewTab(newrdp, serverTextBox.Text, usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text);
```

The reason I include the name is I use another method to find a control by that name on a particular tab so I can disconnect gracefully.